# Sort Java List/Map by order in which items are in an XML File

Tags: java, xml, sorting, business-logic, business-rules

What I'm looking to do is to sorta a Java List or Map in the order the items are in a XML File.

For Example

I have a list of function names as so:

1. functionOne
2. functionThree
3. functionTwo

The XML File looks like this:

```
<xml>
  <function>functionOne</function>
  <function>functionTwo</function>
  <function>functionThree</function>
</xml>
```

So I would like to sort the list so the function names are as so:

1. functionOne
2. functionTwo
3. functionThree

Now Im trying to do this for Variables as well, so there are around 500+ unique 'items'.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this? Now for the file that determines that sort order doesn't have to be XML it just what I use the most, it can be anything that can get the job done.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot just build the list of function names from the xml? I mean, parse xml file first and build your list of functions names in the order they appear in xml as you go.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to define the sort order manually, but not all values are going to appear in all sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the XML file to build a `Map<String,Integer>` which maps the names to their ordinal position.

Then, you need a custom Comparator:

```
public class XMLComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private Map<String,Integer> order;

    public XMLComparator(Map<String,Integer> desiredOrder) {
        order = desiredOrder;
    }

    public void compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return order.get(s1) - order.get(s2);
    }

}
```

then apply it to your list of variable names:

```
Collections.sort(variableNames, new XMLComparator(previouslyCreatedMap));
```

There's probably some edge cases to take care of, but that's the general idea.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be the purpose of the `boolean equals(String other)` method in that comparator?

Comment: @Colin - it's required by the Comparator interface.  Maybe they wanted to see if two comparators were equal to avoid redundant work?

Comment: That would be `boolean equals(Object obj)`. It's also not at all required that you override the default `equals` implementation: "Note that it is _always_ safe _not_ to override `Object.equals(Object)`." You might want to implement `equals` based on the equality of the `order` map for this comparator, but then you'd also need to implement `hashCode` too.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  I wonder why they bothered listing that in the interface at all?

Comment: As a suggestion to people who implement the interface, since many implementations of `Comparator` (this one included) could benefit from a good `equals` method in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an XML parser to read the values from the XML file into a `List` in order rather than taking a different `List` and sorting it according to the order they're found in the XML file. This is assuming that the `List` you're talking about sorting would contain all the values that are found in the XML file.

If it might only contain a subset of the values in the XML file, one option would be to first read in all the values from the XML and then use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Ordering.explicit(List)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit%28java.util.List%29):

```
Ordering<String> orderFromXml = Ordering.explicit(readListFromXml());
List<String> otherList = ...
Collections.sort(otherList, orderFromXml);
```